# Canon LBP6200d printer does not work after upgrading to Ubuntu 14

Tags: printing, canon

After upgrading from Ubuntu 13.10 to Ubuntu 14.04 my Canon CAPT printer LBP6200d  does not work, even though I reinstalled the drivers manually. What changed? Is there a bug?

I tried the troubleshooting steps. The status monitor works (see output below). I then tried verifying the existence of `/var/ccpd/fifo0`. It said it could not find directory or file. I then tried to manually install it as suggested. It said the file existed. Printer still does not print. Output following

```
$ sudo ccpdadmin -p LBP6200 -o /dev/usb/lp0 

 CUPS_ConfigPath = /etc/cups/ 
 LOG Path        = None 
 UI Port         = 59787 

 Entry Num  : Spooler   : Backend   : FIFO path     : Device Path   : Status 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
     [0]    : LBP6200   : ccp       : //localhost:59787     : /dev/usb/lp0 : Modified 



$ ls -l /var/ccpd 
ls: Zugriff auf /var/ccpd nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden 


$ sudo mkdir /var/ccpd 
mkdir: das Verzeichnis »/var/ccpd“ kann nicht angelegt werden: Die Datei existiert bereits 


$ sudo mkfifo /var/ccpd/fifo0 
$ sudo chown -R lp:lp /var/ccpd 
$ sudo ccpdadmin -p LBP6200 -o /dev/usb/lp0 

 CUPS_ConfigPath = /etc/cups/ 
 LOG Path        = None 
 UI Port         = 59787 

 Entry Num  : Spooler   : Backend   : FIFO path     : Device Path   : Status 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
     [0]    : LBP6200   : ccp       : //localhost:59787     : /dev/usb/lp0  : Modified
```

Comment: what driver did you reinstall? Please help us help you!

Comment: I installed, as in Ubuntu 13.10, the Linux_CAPT_PrinterDriver_V260_uk_EN in the same way as in Ubuntu 13.10, when it worked. The printer settings in the system settings seem correct. When I try to print a test page, the printer status says "printing", but nothing happens.

Comment: specifically, the 32 bit debian version.

Comment: I edited the answer adding an additional option. If this works please comment on which option worked for you and upvote/accept the answer so that others with the same issue can find the answer and benefit as well. Thank you.

Comment: While the printer status says printing do you see any flashing lights on the printer? Does the printer feed a page (blank or otherwise)?

Comment: The printer works all right with an apple. But, no flashing lights or page feed. I think it has to do with problems with the printer emulation in 14.04. But maybe the driver provided from Canon does not work with 14.04.

Comment: If there is no indication that the printer is receiving data, it likely isn't

Answer (score 0):

Your printer can work under linux but it's not the easiest to configure. There's a nice article regarding compatibility with some specific ubuntu tricks here:

http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2013-11-01-canon-i-sensys-lbp6200d-laser-printer-a4-mono-duplex and official ubuntu documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190)

If this doesn't work for you try the open-source foo2cap driver available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/foo2capt)

Neither of these specifically mentions 14.04 so please report back with your results.

Comment: I (rather we, someone more familiar with Linux helped me) used the Ubuntu 13.10 instalation guide for CanonCaptDrv190 (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190) plus the suggestions in (http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2013-11-01-canon-i-sensys-lbp6200d-laser-printer-a4-mono-duplex), which worked for Ubuntu 13.10, but do not work for Ubuntu 14.04. I wonder whether other commands may be necessary for Ubuntu 14.04? I did not follow your foo2cap driver suggestion as it does not seem to be compatible with my printer.

Comment: Have we tried the troubleshooting steps at the end of https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190 and if so what was the output?

Comment: I tried the troubleshooting steps. The status monitor works (see output below). I then tried verifying the existence of  /var/ccpd/fifo0. It said it could not find directory or file. I then tried to manually install it as suggested. It said the file existed. Printer still does not print. Output following

Comment: CUPS_ConfigPath = /etc/cups/
 LOG Path        = None
 UI Port         = 59787

 Entry Num  : Spooler : Backend : FIFO path  : Device Path  : Status 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [0]    : LBP6200  : ccp   : //localhost:59787  : /dev/usb/lp0 : Modified
gerhard@gerhard-desktop:~$ sudo mkdir /var/ccpd
mkdir: das Verzeichnis »/var/ccpd“ kann nicht angelegt werden: Die Datei existiert bereits
gerhard@gerhard-desktop:~$ sudo mkfifo /var/ccpd/fifo0
gerhard@gerhard-desktop:~$ sudo chown -R lp:lp /var/ccpd

Comment: Please add the above information in your question. You'll find that you have more room to provide information than you have in a comment.

Comment: I have added that information to my question.